# How to have hyper-reference from endnotes numbers to their corresponding numbers in the main text?

Tags: hyperref, endnotes, enotez

I used `\usepackage{enotez}` to have hyper-reference from numbers in the main text to my endnotes numbers. But I also want hyper-reference the other way around, that is, from endnotes numbers to numbers in the main text. How can I have that.

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{enotez}      % <-- instead of \usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\let\footnote=\endnote

\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\usepackage{changepage}
\frenchspacing
\usepackage{times}

\makeatletter % <-Added code from here
\def\ps@pprintTitle{%
 \let\@oddhead\@empty
 \let\@evenhead\@empty
 \def\@oddfoot{}%
 \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\makeatother


\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\keyword}{\textit}{}{}{}

\usepackage{setspace} 
\doublespacing

\begin{document}


But, in either of the above ways is it defined, why not to take the constraints as securing information too?\footnote{The question was brought up to my attention by John.} 

\printendnotes
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `backref` option as clearly stated in the manual in section `7` on the upper part of page `10`.

The package `footnotebackref` isn't needed here, in my point of view.

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[backref]{enotez}      % <-- instead of \usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\let\footnote=\endnote

\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{natbib}
%\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\usepackage{changepage}
\frenchspacing
\usepackage{times}

\makeatletter % <-Added code from here
\def\ps@pprintTitle{%
 \let\@oddhead\@empty
 \let\@evenhead\@empty
 \def\@oddfoot{}%
 \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\makeatother


\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\keyword}{\textit}{}{}{}

\usepackage{setspace} 
\doublespacing

\begin{document}


But, in either of the above ways is it defined, why not to take the constraints as securing information too?\footnote{The question was brought up to my attention by John.} 

\clearpage
\printendnotes
\end{document}
```